# How can I pass array of objects as arguments to a RESTful service

Tags: c#

I've a types class, which contains key and value properties and I need to send array of types objects to restful service. I tried the below url, but its not working. Please correct it. Thanks in advance.

http://localhost:8080/CRService/services/CRService/newContentObjectRequest?User=abcd&types={"key":name, "value":xyz}&types={"key":assigned_to, "value":abcd}&types={"key":status, "value":COMPLETED}

Comment: That should be POST data not sent in the URL

Comment: Typically, arrays are not passed in the URL. You can send XML as part of the request (i.e. as part of the POST) to your service.

Comment: I tried by sending through xml. got the below error : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the documentation of the restful service. It appears that it is expecting the data in JSON format.

You would need to send the data as a HTTP POST request.